# How to make a `NavHostFragment` respond to `onBackPressed` when inside another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have an `Activity` with a `NavHostFragment` nested in a `Fragment`:

- Root `View` of the `Activity`

  - `Fragment`

    - `NavHostFragment`

as I go navigating in the NavGraph, a *back stack* for `NavHostFragment` is being created. But as soon as I click on the back button of the device, instead of going to the previous `Fragment` of the *back stack*, the app closes (as if there were no *back stack*).

Am I missing something? Is there any coupling between the `NavHostFragment` and `Fragment` that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the [interact programmatically with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#create_a_navhostfragment), it is the call to [setPrimaryNavigationFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setPrimaryNavigationFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) that hooks Fragments up to the system back button.

Each fragment in the hierarchy must have `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` set. While the `NavHostFragment` may be calling that itself if you are inflating it from XML and using `app:defaultNavHost="true"`, you also need to explicitly call it on your parent fragment.

```
// In your Activity's onCreate() when you add the parent fragment
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Fragment parent = new ParentFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, parent)
        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(parent)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, @ianhanniballake \o/. It solved the problem :)